# Retrieve blob file name in Copy Data activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I download json files from a web API and store them in blob storage using a Copy Data activity and binary copy. Next I would like to use another Copy Data activity to extract a value from each json file in the blob container and store the value together with its ID in a database. The ID is part of the filename, but is there some way to extract the filename?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following set of activities:

1) A GetMetadata activity, configure a dataset pointing to the blob folder, and add the Child Items in the Field List.

2) A forEach activity that takes every item from the GetMetadata activity and iterates over them. To do this you configure the Items to be @activity('NameOfGetMetadataActivity').output.childItems

3) Inside the foreach, you can extract the filename of each file using the following function: item().name

After this continue as you see fit, either adding functions to get the ID or copy the entire name.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping I could avoid using a ForEach activity, since it can be hundreds of thousands of files, so I would prefer some batch activity that could parse all files in one go.

Comment: I don't see how are you going to do that with data factory without using ForEach, also if you are avoiding this option then make sure to tell us when asking

Answer (score 0):

After Setting up Dataset for source file/file path with wildcard and destination/sink as some table

1. Add Copy Activity setup source, sink
2. Add Additional Columns
3. Provide a name to the additional column and value "$$FILEPATH"
4. Import Mapping and voila - your additional column should be in the list of source columns marked "Additional"

[image: Setup]