# Azure Data Factory Get Metadata to get blob filenames and transfer them to Azure SQL database table

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, metadata, azure-data-factory, copydataset

I am trying to use Get Metadata activity in Azure Data Factory in order to get blob filenames and copy them to Azure SQL database table.
I follow this tutorial: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6246/azure-data-factory-get-metadata-example/

Here is my pipeline, Copy Data > Source is the source destination of the blob files in my Blob storage. I need to specify my source file as binary because they are *.jpeg files.

[image: GetMetadata0]

For my Copy Data > Sink, its the Azure SQL database, I enable the option "Auto Create table"

[image: GetMetadata1]

In my Sink dataset config, I had to choose one table because the validation won't pass if I don't select the table in my SQL database even though this table is not related at all to the blob filenames that I want to get.

[image: GetMetadata2]

Question 1: Am I supposed to create a new table in SQL DB before to have the columns matching the blob filenames that I want to extract?

Then, I tried to validate the pipeline and I get this error.

```
Copy_Data_1
Sink must be binary when source is binary dataset.
```

[image: Getmetadata3]

Question 2: How can I resolve this error? I had to select the file type of the source as binary as it's one of the step when creating source dataset. Therefore, when I choose sink dataset that is Azure SQL table, I didn't have to select the type of dataset so it doesn't seem to match.

Thank you very much in advance.

New screenshot of the new pipeline, I can now get itemName of filenames in the json output files.

[image: GetFileName1]

Now I add Copy Data activity just after Get_File_Name2 activity and connect them together to try to get the json output files as source dataset.

[image: GetFileName2]

However, I need to choose the source dataset location first before specify type as json. But, as far as I understand these output json files are the output from Get_File_Name2 activity and they are not yet stored on Blob storage. How do I make the copy data activity reading these json output file as source dataset?

[image: GetFileName3]

*****Update 10/14/2020*****
Here is my new activity stored procedure, I added the parameter as suggested however, I changed the name to JsonData as my stored procedure requires this parameter.

[image: storedprocedure1]

This is my stored procedure.

[image: storedprocedure2]

I get this error at the stored procedure:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2402",
    "message": "Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 13609. Error Message: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'S' is found at position 0.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Stored procedure1",
    "details": []
}
```

[image: storedprocedure3]

But when I check the input, it seems like it already successfully reading the json string itemName.

[image: storedprocedure4]

But, when I check output, it's not there.

[image: storedprocedure5]

Comment: The source files are *.jpeg(image) files not data file like csv, and Binary format can not load to Azure SQL database. It's not supported. We can not help you solve it!

Comment: Hello @Leon Yue could you please check my steps again? I didn’t try to load jpeg files themselves into SQL table of course that wouldn’t make sense as we don’t keep image files i. Relational DB. I was trying to get the filenames of jpeg files and put them in SQL table. That’s why I tried to use Get Metadata, is this the right way to do?

Comment: Yes, it is. But please don't use binary as the source in copy active. Your whole workflow may be: Get metadata(get all the .jpeg files name)--> foreach(loop the filename)--> if condition( I don't know what it used for)-->true active(load to Azure SQL).

Comment: Auto create table doesn't work for filename! It depends on the file data. You need create a table to receive these filenames.

Comment: Hello @Leon Yue thank you very much for your suggestion. I also found similar solution so I modified my pipeline like this:
Get Metadata 1 with dataset pointing to blob files on blob storage, here I add file list = Child items
Then this is connected to ForEach loop with setting @activity('Get_File_Name1').output.childItems and with activity inside of Get Metadata also pointing to blob storage with FileName value as @item().name. After running this pipeline, it seems getting close as in json output files, I get itemName value of filename. Please, see screenshot above.

Comment: @Leon Yue now my question is how do I put this itemName from json output file on an output activity in Azure Data Factory so that I can put this later in SQL. Is there an a way to put this in CSV or something?

Comment: You could specify the output json name, then just create a new copy active, set he source(json file name)  and choose stored procedure in Azure SQL database as Sink. It will work.

Comment: Actually, you may could using Get metadata output json as the parameter and then call the stored procedure: Get metedata-->Stored Procedure! You just need focus on the coding of the stored procedure!

Comment: @Leon Yue  thank you for this suggestion. I did add Copy Data activity just after Get_File_Name2 where I see the json output. However, this is my struggle part, with Copy data activity, I need to specify source dataset location first before I can specify the stype json. For now, these json output files are the output from the previous Get_File_Name2 activity so they are not on Blob storage. How to I make the copy data activity to read these json file as source input data set? I am sorry as I am new to Azure Data Factory. Please, see new scereenshots above.

Comment: Please see my answer, hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you may could using Get metadata output json as the parameter and then call the stored procedure: `Get metedata`-->`Stored Procedure`!

You just need focus on the coding of the stored procedure.

Get Metadata output `childitems`:

```
{
   "childItems": [
        {
            "name": "DeploymentFiles.zip",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "geodatalake.pdf",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "test2.xlsx",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "word.csv",
            "type": "File"
        }
}
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems
```

[image]

About how to create the stored procedure(get data from json object), you could ref this blog: [Retrieve JSON Data from SQL Server using a Stored Procedure](https://chris.koester.io/index.php/2018/03/25/retrieve-json-data-from-sql-server-using-a-stored-procedure-and-csharp/).

Comment: Hello @Leon Yue thank you so much for your help. I am going to try this. Just one question, so you think I don't need to use ForEach loop Activity between Get Metadata and Store Procedure right? I added ForEach loop activity as I saw another reply from this thread here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764072/retrieve-blob-file-name-in-copy-data-activity

Comment: Sorry another question, does this mean I am supposed to create a table first (along with the stored procedure) in my Azure SQL database? Before doing this workflow?

Comment: @Shuti Yes, you don't need the foreach. Create the table first and using stored procedure to insert the data from get metadata output. The get metadata output as the stored procedure parameter.

Comment: Ok thank you very much @Leon Yue, I will try this and let you know if this works

Comment: @Shuti ok, hope things going well!

Comment: Hello again, sorry it took me sometimes to write a stored procedure. I tried this and I get this error in my pipeline execution at stored procedure. I updated my question above with the date today. Could you please help me check? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @Shuti to make the question more clear, I would suggest you post another question.  More people can see it and could help you assist .

Comment: you are right. I opened a new question here. Please, let me know if you can find out the issue here. Thank you in advance.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352195/azure-data-factory-get-metadata-to-get-blob-filenames-and-transfer-them-to-azure

Comment: @Shuti Sure,I can see it.