# Azure Data Factory Get Metadata to get blob filenames and transfer them to Azure SQL database table part 2

Tags: json, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use Get Metadata activity in Azure Data Factory in order to get blob filenames and copy them to Azure SQL database table.
I added the stored procedure activity after Get Metadata activity. Here is my new activity stored procedure, I added the parameter as suggested however, I changed the name to JsonData as my stored procedure requires this parameter.

[image: storedprocedure1]

This is my stored procedure.

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertDataJSON]    Script Date: 10/14/2020 11:01:30 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/*USE datafactorypoc1*/

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDataJSON] (
    @JsonData NVARCHAR (MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @err int

    INSERT INTO extractFileNameTest1 (ItemName, ItemType, EffIntegrationRunTieme, ExecutionDuration, DurationInQueue)
    SELECT ItemName, ItemType, EffIntegrationRunTieme, ExecutionDuration, DurationInQueue
    FROM OPENJSON (@JsonData, N'$') WITH (
        ItemName VARCHAR(255) N'$.ItemName',
        ItemType VARCHAR(255) N'$.ItemType',
        EffIntegrationRunTieme VARCHAR(255) N'$.EffIntegrationRunTieme',
        ExecutionDuration INT N'$.ExecutionDuration',
        DurationInQueue INT N'$.DurationInQueue'
    )    

    SELECT @err = @@ERROR
    RETURN (@err)
END
```

[image: storedprocedure2]

I get this error at the stored procedure:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2402",
    "message": "Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 13609. Error Message: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'S' is found at position 0.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Stored procedure1",
    "details": []
}
```

[image: storedprocedure3]

But when I check the input, it seems like it already successfully reading the json string itemName.

[image: storedprocedure4]

But, when I check output, it's not there.

[image: storedprocedure5]

Could you please help me check what I did wrong here? Is it my stored procedure? Thank you very much in advance.

*****Update 15/10/2020*****
I created a new pipeline and move the Stored Procedure inside ForEach activity to connect to Get_Filename_2 instead of the first one ad followed:

[image: ADFPipelineTwo1]

Here I changed the value of parameter to Get_Filename_2 and output as itemName instead of childitems (because I got an error with using childitems because childitems is from Get_Filename_1 and not 2).

[image: ADFpipelinetwo2]

After executing the pipeline (which was failed), the input of the last stored procedure is:

```
{
    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[InsertDataJSON]",
    "storedProcedureParameters": {
        "JsonData": {
            "value": "FRRNSC84FIN1_A2276801_20200103-152534.json",
            "type": "String"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ADFpipelinetwo3]

And the output is:

```
{
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (West Europe)",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image: ADFpipelinetwo4]

For this pipeline, it's failed with following error message.

```
{
    "errorCode": "2402",
    "message": "Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 13609. Error Message: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'F' is found at position 0.\r\nFRRNSC84FIN1_A2276801_20200103-152534.json",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Stored procedure1",
    "details": []
}
```

[image: ADFpipelinetwo4]

On my old pipeline where I have stored procedure outside of ForEach loop. The pipeline did not fail:

[image: ADFpipeline1]

Here is the input of the last stored procedure activity:

```
{
    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[InsertDataJSON]",
    "storedProcedureParameters": {
        "JsonData": {
            "value": "[{\"name\":\"FRRNSC84FIN1_A2274001_20200103-143748_back_camera_0.jpeg\",\"type\":\"File\"},{\"name\":\"FRRNSC84FIN1_A2274001_20200103-143748_right_camera_0.jpeg\",\"type\":\"File\"},{\"name\":\"FRRNSC84FIN1_A2274801_20200103-144811_right_camera_0.jpeg\",\"type\":\"File\"},{\"name\":\"FRRNSC84FIN1_A2275201_20200103-145229_right_camera_0.jpeg\",\"type\":\"File\"},{\"name\":\"FRRNSC84FIN1_A2276801_20200103-152534.json\",\"type\":\"File\"}]"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ADFpipieline2]

And here is the output:

```
{
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (West Europe)",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image: ADFpipeline3]

This pipeline ran successfully however the result in the SQL is not what I really expected, also many NULL values before the first json string but it insert all itemName in the same location. This is because it's outside of ForEach loop I think. But why it insert so many NULL?

[image: SQLresult]

Here is my stored procedure that I modified:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertDataJSON]    Script Date: 15/10/2020 10:31:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/*USE datafactorypoc1*/

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDataJSON] (
    @JsonData NVARCHAR (MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT @JsonData

    /*INSERT INTO Logs values (DEFAULT, @JsonData)*/
    INSERT INTO extractFileNameTest1 values (@JsonData, DEFAULT)
    SELECT * FROM
        OPENJSON (@JsonData)
    WITH (
        ItemName VARCHAR(255) N'$.ItemName',
        ItemType VARCHAR(255) N'$.ItemType'
    )
END
```

I tried to delete all data in my test SQL table to see the output of the 2nd fail pipeline. I notice that it did parse correctly the json string filename inside my table and all of them (I only have 5 files in blob storage). But other data are NULL.

[image: ADFpipelinetwo6]

To conclude, the result in SQL table of the new pipeline is much better, each file name on the different cell of the table but I got pipeline run failed. Could you please help me check what I did wrong here? Is it the stored procedure or the expression in my last Stored procedure activity inside ForEach loop?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Pleas show us the settings and output of the "Get_File_Name1".  And you have a get metaata active "Get_File_Name2" in foreach contained active. I guess that you are using Foreach to loop the files name(`Get_File_Name1.output.childtiems`) and using "Get_File_Name2" to get the file `item name`. Then the stored procedure should connect to the "Get_File_Name2" not after foreach.

Comment: Hello thank you very much for your reply @Leon Yue I did more test on a new pipeline to compare the result. I updated my question above as I cannot place screenshot here. Could you please help me check? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm trying  to repeat the error. I create the stored procedure in SSMS and it's strange that I also can't get itemName and itemType, it's `null` at my side too. Still need time to figure out it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this @Leon Yue, it’s really strange

Comment: Yeah, it makes me have a headache and  lose my hair!

Comment: @LeonYue Thank you for your help. I have found a solution on my side, thanks to my friend. I will share a solution to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario, I use only 1 Get Metadata activity with:
Dataset of Get Metadata activity = Binary files from Blob storage
Field List of Get Metadata = Child items

This Get Metadata activity has output connected to ForEach activity:
ForEach activity settings => Items => @activity('Get_FileName_1').output.childItems

Inside ForEach activity, there is 1 activity which is Stored Procedure:
Stored Procedure Settings has Linked Service = Azure SQL Database with selected Stored Procedure. In the stored procedure that I wrote, I defined the columns that I will read from blob file names. Then, for the parameters of Stored Procedure activity, I define exact same parameters numbers = all columns of @JsonData in stored procedure.
Then, for each value of the parameter, I use Azure Data Factory function @substring to extract different parts of blob file name. Then insert these to the correct columns in Azure SQL table.

Source for Substring function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#substring

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue while loading output of `get_metadata` activity with help of `sp`.

The simple answer is while feeding output of `get_metadata` activity to `SP` parameter, you need to convert it to string. Like below:

`@string(activity('get_metadata').output.childitems)`